# How to send notifications to a specific user with AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am developing an app like Dominoes. In which, I would like to send a Push notification to the Customer, when his/her Order is prepared.

I had been using OneSignal to do so (through sending notification to a particular player id), and now we would like to do it with AWS SNS Service, as we are using bunch of different AWS Services too.

---

We don't want any marketing/bulk push notifications, the SNS Service would do only one thing - send a particular message from the Restaurants' Mobile (using REST API), and it would reach the Customer's mobile.

With OneSignal, we used to give the PlayerID/UserID of the receiver. Does this method apply to AWS SNS too? Also, we could only work with HTTPS POST requests in our platform.

Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to send an SMS to a Phone Number, or send a message to a mobile app registered with Apple/Google?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I would send push notifications, to my android app. The Shop App would send the message from his app through REST API, and the Customer would receive a push notification on his/her device, like most of the apps do. Thanks!

Comment: Both SNS and Amplify support mobile push.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod for the reply! Can you refer any documents/tutorials which could help in configuring it? Thanks!

Comment: For SNS, start at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send.html